# Why doesn't PStricks put nodes where I want?

Tags: pstricks, pstricks-add

I was surprised when I saw this result!

I want to put, starting from my lower left corner, a pink, a red, and a blue node,

BUT

I was surprised when I saw that the three nodes started from the upper right corner!

I solved the problem by changing -0.25 to 0

BUT, WHY does PStricks do this?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{standalone}
\usepackage{setspace} % para que no afecte el interlineado a las notas de pié de página
\setstretch{1.5}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,latexsym}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, urlcolor=blue}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathpazo}       % Fuente MathPazo
\usepackage{datetime}       % paquete para configurar formato de fecha y hora
\settimeformat{ampmtime}
\renewcommand*{\noon}{\pmname}

\spanishdecimal{.}
% ----------------------  PSTRICKS ---------------
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-3dplot,pst-node,pst-tree,pst-grad,pst-coil,pst-text,pst-3d,pst-eps,pst-fill,pstricks-add,multido}
% -------- Paquetes de pst-all \usepackage{pst-all}   paquete pstricks para las figuras en postcript
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{pst-eps}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
% ---- Fin Paquetes de pst-all
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-0.25,-0.25)(14.50,10.20) %\malla
\psset{xunit=1cm,yunit=1cm}
\psframe[fillcolor=lightgray,fillstyle=solid,linestyle=none](-0.25,-0.25)(14.50,10.20)

\cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink](1,1){0.15}{Current}
\cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red](4,1){0.15}{Current}
\cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue](8,1){0.15}{Current}

 \end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Try substituting -0.25 with 0 in `pspicture` and in `psframe`. It solves the problem!

Answer (score 2):

Please provide *minimal* examples!
Ghostscript is too clever here. It thinks that your page should rotated. Use `xelatex` or `ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages=/None  <file>.ps` or show the grid, then you'll get it upright:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-node}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=top](-0.5,-0.5)(14.50,10.20) %\malla
\psframe[fillcolor=lightgray,fillstyle=solid,linestyle=none,opacity=0.4](-0.25,-0.25)(14.50,10.20)
\cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink](1,1){0.15}{Current}
\cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red](4,1){0.15}{Current}
\cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue](8,1){0.15}{Current}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know where I must type -dAtuo.... ?  Usually I click the icon in WinEdt!

Comment: See http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=pdf/pdfoutput#WinEdt

Answer (score 0):

The minimal working example to reproduce your issue is given as follows.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(4,3)
    \psframe(4,3)
    \rput{90}(2,1.5){A}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Note that `showgrid` must be `false` (by default).

Compiling with `latex`, followed by `dvips`, followed by `ps2pdf` will produce an auto-rotated output as follows.

[image]

To avoid this issue, pass `-dAutoRotatePages=/None` to `ps2pdf`. By doing so, you will get what you want to get as follows.

[image]

### Simulation

The following simulates the scenario in a self-contained code. Make sure you compile it with `pdflatex -shell-escape simulation.tex`.

```
% simulation.tex

\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{diagram.tex}
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(4,3)
    \psframe(4,3)
    \rput{90}(2,1.5){A}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{graphicx,pgffor}
\def\PreventAutoRotate{\foreach \compiler/\ext in {latex/tex,dvips/dvi,{ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages=/None}/ps}{\immediate\write18{\compiler\space diagram.\ext}}}
\def\LetAutoRotate{\foreach \compiler/\ext in {latex/tex,dvips/dvi,ps2pdf/ps}{\immediate\write18{\compiler\space diagram.\ext}}}

\begin{document}
\PreventAutoRotate
%\LetAutoRotate
\noindent\includegraphics{diagram}
\end{document}
```